# Смех(,) да и только

Tags: пунктуация

"Смех(,) да и только" — нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, запятая здесь не нужна. Это устойчивое выражение, союз "да и" используется  для подтверждения, усиления высказанного суждения: *Вот так случай, смех да и только.*

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, так как это цельное выражение. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/165490/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85